# Join 2 tables to a Pivot table LARAVEL 4.2

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-4, inner-join, pivot-table

How can i show the classes  only for student who is enrolled in a class and i have 2 tables and a pivot table?

Table 1: **Home_Students** : home_id , home_studid ....

Table 2: **Hw_Classes** :class_id , class_desc , class_date ....

Pivot table:**Hw_StudentClasses** :Stclass_id, Stclass_classid, Stclass_studid

So i made a model **MySeminarClasses** to communicate with the table **Hw_StudentClasses** and a Controller **MySeminarClassesController**

I made relations in the model of the other tables belongsToMany

```
public function Users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','home_id');

}
public function SeminarClass(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('SeminarClass','class_id');

}
```

*Also in the Controller i did this which im not so sure if its right but i did this from the instructions of the laravel 4.2 documentation*

```
$myclasses = DB::table('Hw_StudentClasses')
    ->join('Hw_Classes','Hw_StudentClasses.Stclass_classid','=','Hw_Classes.Class_id')
    ->join('Home_Students','Hw_StudentClasses.Stclass_studid','=','Home_Students.home_studid')
    ->orderBy('class_date',strtotime('-4 month'))
    ->get();
```

Finally in the blade

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($myclasses as $i=>$myclass)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $i+1 }}</td>
            **<td>{{ link_to_route('class.show',$myclass->Class_desc,$myclass->Class_id) }}</td>**
            <td class="text-center">{{ date('j-n-Y G:i',strtotime($myclass->class_date)) }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ UserEnroll::where('Stclass_classid',$myclass->Class_id)->count() }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a 16 hours of struggle ......i aswered my own question ! This query with **Auth::user** helped me. Show the classes only for every user who is logged in

```
$id = Auth::user()->home_studid;
$date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('-4 month'));
$seminars = Seminar::where('Package_Display', 1)
            ->orWhere('Package_Display', 2)
            ->orderBy('Package_Name', 'asc')
            ->get();


$myclasses = DB::table('Hw_StudentClasses')
            ->join('Hw_Classes','Hw_StudentClasses.Stclass_classid','=','Hw_Classes.Class_id')
            ->join('Home_Students','Hw_StudentClasses.Stclass_studid','=','Home_Students.home_studid')
            ->where('Home_Students.home_studid','=',$id)
            ->orderBy('class_date',strtotime('-4 month'))
            ->get();
```

HOPE THIS HELPS SOMEONE ! ^_^